# Gallery opens again after the user clicks on an image

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I am using the code below to fire an intent and open the android Gallery, in order to let the user choose an image.

```
 userProfileImage.setOnClickListener(v ->
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, GalleryPick);
        });
```

The Gallery opens up fine, but when the user clicks on an image, the app shows "Select source" and all the apps that can open an image. If the user clicks on one of them, they have to choose the image again, and only then will it proceed. The code below shows my code after I get the result:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == GalleryPick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null)
        {
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);
        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                loadingBar.setTitle("Set Profile Image");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                loadingBar.show();

                assert result != null;
                final Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                final StorageReference filePath = userProfileImagesRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");
                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                    final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                    rootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("image").setValue(downloadUrl)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(task ->
                            {
                                if (task.isSuccessful())
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile image stored to firebase database successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                }
                                else
                                    {
                                        String message = Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage();
                                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error Occurred..." + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                    }
                            });
                }));
            }
            else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE)
            {
                assert result != null;
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }

        }
    }
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this? I would prefer to let the user choose the app they want to open the image with.

Comment: Please debug your code to see if some order code is triaging multiple time when you click on image

Comment: I please request you to provide the code of whole Activity.

Comment: @Arslan let me rephrase. When a user clicks on the image view to select an image, the Android Gallery opens. After that if the user clicks on an image, then the Gallery closes and multiple choices appear on screen with which the user may select an image. One of those is the Gallery. I can provide the logs if you want me to.